# Website in 4k resolution scaled to fit a smaller window

Tags: html, css, iframe, iframe-resizer

I have a website I created in 4k resolution (3840 x 2160) that I want to display in an iframe. I've been using chrome inspector tool to create the website in the desired resolution. Is there a way to display the iframe in lets say a 1920 x 1080 iframe and the inner iframe (the website) display in the native resolution? The solutions i've found don't seem to scale properly. Is there a way to create an iframe that mimics the chrome dev tools responsive scaling?

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    height: 0;
}
 .responsive-iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <iframe
    class="responsive-iframe"
    src="http://website.com"
  ></iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: iframes cant use a height attribute of 100%. It needs a definite value as pixels. However. The soultion to all problems would eb a responsive web design. A web design that only works on 4k resolution while the majority of all screens is way below it, can be considered as un-responsive.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
    .outher{
        position: relative;
        width: 800px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100vh;
    }
    .iframe{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 1920px;
        height: 1080px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="outher">
        <iframe
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OC738Vw-zcg"
                class="iframe">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

you have to set a `<div>` arround. And then set the iframe rendersize with the `width` and `height` tag (in this sample 1920x1080).